# Is File Writer speeding up my FPS of my captured streaming videos?

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

I have a webcam hooked up in graphedit, and in C# code, all the videos i save are being saved 2-3 times faster then they are being streamed at. The webcam is setup to run 640x480 @ 30fps. I record a video for 15 seconds and when i replay it, the video is only 5 seconds long, it contains the entire 15second video but just at a higher FPS.

I have changed my filters around a bit. I have used ffdshow encoders, xvid encoders, mpeg encoders, divx encoders along with avi mux, xvid mux, mpeg mux, all connected to File Writer and they are all saving the video stream at higher FPS.

So is File Writer doing something it shouldnt?

Is there a way to fix it or work around it?

or maybe a better option?

EDIT:

These are the graphs I've been trying to use but all the outputs are at a sped up FPS

```
Source -> Smart Tee -> 3ivx MPEG-4 Video Encoder -> 3ivx MPEG-4 Media Muxer -> File Writer

Source -> Smart Tee -> Divx Video Encoder -> AVI Mux -> file writer

Source -> Smart Tee -> ffdshow video encoder -> 3ivx MPEG-4 Media Muxer -> file writer

Source -> Smart Tee -> AVI Mux -> File Writer
```

with all these graphs, I recorded a 15 second video and when they were replayed, they were 5 seconds long

Comment: The speed at which it saves the *same bits* has nothing to do with the playback speed.  We'll need a lot more info to help solve this problem.  Possibly some code.

Comment: right now its not even working in graphedit let alone code so to make it easy ill post the graphs

Comment: This is possibly a bug in the webcam software. Does it come with its own software, and if it does, does it work okay there?

Comment: It streams fine. It comes with software to stream and stream over IP but nothing to save video. I do however have other types of cameras to test against. Per you comment i tried another one out and it saved a 15 second video and replayed it 15seconds so apparently the hardware/firmware isnt correct of this camera

Comment: Similar issue is commented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173122/directshow-record-problem-fps

Comment: I know and have been watching it and i tried the dump filter but it dumps everything to a file and nothing comes of it. cant read it, cant render. i created a graph that reads 3 different usb cameras straight into a respective dump file. all 3 were saved as .txts and .asfs and opened in a hexeditor. All 3 were completely different, and none of the 3 opened in a media player

Answer (score 0):

You need to check timestamps of samples coming out of your web cam and also frame duration mentioned in the media type of its stream. The former can be done easily in [GraphEditPlus](http://www.infognition.com/GraphEditPlus/) by inserting a sample grabber after the web cam and watching grabbed samples info (right click the grabber). The latter is even easier: just click the connection.