# DirectShow C++ : wrong duration and Fps in resulting avi file

Tags: c++, directshow, duration, avi, frame-rate

I have a directshow graph as described below :
"File.mov"->haali Splitter->ffdshow decoder ->Custom Filter->avi Mux->File writer(File.avi).

The Fps of the original file is 30 Fps (File.mov) and the duration is 6 seconds.

**Behaviour in the prompt:** When I run the application in the prompt, I obtain a file with a duration of about 12seconds and Fps of 25. What is done, is that each frame is duplicated twice.

**Behaviour in Graphedit Tools:** When I run the same graph in Graphedit, the playback is progressing until the progress bar is full, but never stops(stop button doesn't change to grey).  If I force stop with the Stop Button, the File.avi is automatically removed from the disc.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

See discussion at [DirectShow Record Problem - fps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173122/directshow-record-problem-fps)

The avi file format does not have per-frame timestamps. If the media type frame rate that is used for the file creation doesn't match the timestamps you pass, the mux will create dropped frame markers.

G

Comment: would you have an explanations why the graph don't stop automatically when It finished reading the original video?